# How to query Solr with auto-suggested/spell-corrected keyword in one request?

Tags: solr, autosuggest, fieldcollapsing

Many popular search dropdowns on sites like Amazon ([example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydzEe.jpg)) use autosuggested words along with grouping (Field Collapsing in Solr).

While I can replicate the same functionality in Solr using two requests (first to obtain suggestions, second for the actual query using the most probable suggestion), I want to know if this can be done in one request itself.

I understand that there are various ways to obtain suggestions (term component, facets, Solr's inbuilt ([Suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester)), and I'm open to using any one of them, if it means I'll be able to get everything (groups + suggestions) in one request.

Comment: did you get any one request solution? if yes can you post answer for your own question?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it yet.. but i try this for my auto_suggest..

[Auto Suggestion With multi words/terms using SOLR](http://androidyou.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-auto-suggesting-with-multi.html)

Comment: Doesn't address how I'd get grouping working along with autosuggest. As I said, getting autosuggest to work singly is pretty straight-forward, what I want to know is if getting groups with the most likely suggestion is possible in the same request.